# Subtract all oracle tables with prefix USER from tables with prefix ALL in single statement

Tags: sql, oracle

Test question that i can't find an answer to.

So, i have Oracle DB installed, and it contains a lot of tables with prefixes **USER** and **ALL**.

HOW can i in a **Single** statement subtract the amount of tables with prefix 'ALL' 
 From  amount of tables with prefix 'USER'?

There are ~378 'USER' tables and ~330 'ALL' tables. So i should get an answer somewhere around 48.

Please help. Thanx.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a conditional `COUNT` and filter only the tables needed in where clause(optional, but efficient).

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN table_name like 'ALL%'  THEN 1 END) - COUNT(
             CASE WHEN table_name like 'USER%' THEN 1 END) as diff
   FROM all_tables 
WHERE  table_name LIKE 'ALL%' OR table_name LIKE 'USER%';
```

Comment: THAT WORKED!! thank you. I only had to replace ALL and USER with places, becouse there are more USER tables and also changes ALL_TABLES to DICT. Problem solved. thanx again.

Answer (score 1):

Use view  `ALL_TABLES`, or view `DICT` :

```
SELECT al.cnt - us.cnt
FROM 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM all_tables WHERE table_name like 'ALL%') al,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM all_tables WHERE table_name like 'USER%') us
```

Or :

```
SELECT al.cnt - us.cnt
FROM 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM dict WHERE table_name like 'ALL%') al,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM dict WHERE table_name like 'USER%') us
```

Please note that this will list tables in all schemas. You might want to restrict to a specific schema using column OWNER.

Comment: ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00936: missing expression. Also if i try to count separately USER and ALL from ALL_TABLES it gives 0.  But when i try DICT, than it shows the right values.